# Want to implement boost like signal template which takes function type as a parameter

Tags: c++

Sorry if the question is very basis. I am unable to find somehow to see one simple example code for template implementation as **Boost.signals**
like:

```
 boost::signal<void ()> sig;
```

What i know is the below:

```
 template <class T>
  TemplateClass {
      T t;
   };


   TemplateClass<int> a;
```

Kindly provide few pointers on it?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what the question is, but the thing with boost signals, is that you create a publisher/subscriber system so that you can dispatch events to interested parties.

The declaration -boost::signal sig;- is a simple template like the one you list below it but the type is a function signature (Not to be confused with a function pointer). Subscribers can then provide callbacks with that signature.

Here is a simple hello world example:

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/doc/html/signals/tutorial.html#id3193274

Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

Do you want how to create boost::signals2::signal like template parameter?
Implementation sample is here:

```
#include <tuple>

template <class Signature>
class TemplateClass; // declaration only

template <class R, class... Args>
class TemplateClass<R(Args...)> { // partial specialization as function like signature
public:
    typedef R result_type;
    typedef std::tuple<Args...> arg_types;

    R operator()(const Args&... args)
    {
        return invoke_function(args...);
    }
};

int main()
{
    TemplateClass<void(int, double)> x;
    x(1, 3.14);
}
```